# Problem with KVM switch and erratic mouse movement on windows server 2008

Tags: mouse, windows-server-2008, kvm-switch

I recently installed a PS/2 KVM switch that is connecting two Ubuntu servers and a Windows 2008 server. It worked fine with the Ubuntu boxes, but on the Windows box whenever I try to move the mouse the pointer jumps all over the screen and acts as though the buttons and scroll wheel have been clicked/moved in a seemingly random pattern.

I tried shutting down all of the boxes and disconnecting both Ubuntu boxes from the KVM and resetting the KVM, but when I rebooted the Windows server the problem persisted. If I plug the mouse directly into the Windows server, it works normally, but if I plug it back into the KVM switch the problem returns. Does anyone know of any way of stopping this?

Answer (score 2):

**Using qemu command line**

Add " -usb -usbdevice tablet" to your qemu commandline.

You will get a properly working mouse in your guests without any re-configuration of your guests. The host's mouse position will be used in the guest even without having to click inside the window to give it focus.

**Using virt-manager**

The equivalent for that is to open up the virtual machine details > Add Hardware > Input > EvTouch USB Graphics Tablet.

I always select "USB Connected Mouse" during the Slackware install for the mouse type but I don't think it matters.

**[Source](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/mouse-cursor-in-kvm-guest-4175575243/)**

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with the COM port. You are probably using a device on a COM port that windows detects as a mouse (COM1 default). Disable the COM port mouse rather than uninstalling and restarting the system.

According to [TalTech](http://www.taltech.com/support/entry/windows_2000_nt_serial_mice_and_missing_com_port):

> Since the release of Windows XP and NT, whenever Windows boots up, it searches for a serial mouse on any built in COM ports on your PC. The way that it does this is to look for any data at all coming in the serial port at boot time. If Windows sees data coming in a COM port at boot time, it loads a mouse driver for that COM port. The consequences of this are that the COM port becomes unavailable to any other program, and that any data received through the COM port could potentially be interpreted as mouse movements and clicks causing your PC’s mouse cursor to jump erratically and uncontrollably. It can even cause your PC to crash.

Comment: Thats an interesting theory, but backing it up with sources would seriously improve your answer.

Comment: This was definitely not it. I did not have anything plugged into the COM port, and the mouse would only move erratically when the actual mouse was moving.